# Selenium Test execution via Jenkins on Ubunt server 16.04 without GUI (CLI-only) - HEADLESS MODE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing Selenium Automation Testing via Jenkins.

I have done `Jenkins` setup on my PC and run tests as `Maven` project. It works without problem.

Jenkins is setup on a Ubuntu server without GUI (CLI Only).

- I've installed an additional plugin `Xvfb` in Jenkins
- Set a Global properties `DISPLAY:0` IN Jenkins
- Also on Ubunt server set variable

  ```
  root@jenkins:~# echo $DISPLAY :0
  ```

So when I run the selenium scripts via Jenkins I got the following error:

> runBrowser(testCases.ApplicationTableTempl)  Time elapsed: 1.068 sec 
>   <<< FAILURE! java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server
>   using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method) at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
>   at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103) at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
>   at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.(XToolkit.java:126) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at
>   java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860) at
>   java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854) at
>   utility.Utility.startRecording(Utility.java:183) at
>   testCases.ApplicationTableTempl.runBrowser(ApplicationTableTempl.java:31)
>
> runBrowser(testCases.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 0.196 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   sun.awt.X11.XToolkit at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at
>   java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860) at
>   java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854) at
>   utility.Utility.startRecording(Utility.java:183) at
>   testCases.LoginTest.runBrowser(LoginTest.java:34)
>
> Results :
>
> Failed tests: ApplicationTableTempl.runBrowser:31 » AWT Can't connect
>   to X11 window server u... LoginTest.runBrowser:34 » NoClassDefFound
>   Could not initialize class sun.awt.X...

Anyone suggest me  how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks the root cause comes from your own code:

> testCases.LoginTest.runBrowser -> utility.Utility.startRecording -> java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit

Remove the dependence to `java.awt.Toolkit` in `utility.Utility.startRecording`, and it should not fail.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. I could resolve it by logging into server as a root and execute below command.

```
$ xhost +
```

Answer (score 0):

I just comment out in my code and now it don't use function to screen video record (startRecording). See [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/AsoJkCvurSkR) and [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/VFUM4QkSI)

I tried:

```
root@jenkins:~# xhost +
```

and got following response:

```
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"
```

In Jenkins I got following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Test case = ApplicationTableTempl
browserName = chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1) on port 10447
Only local connections are allowed.
Feb 08, 2017 4:01:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[0.219][SEVERE]: Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/var/lib/jenkins/.pki/nssdb): libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[0.219][SEVERE]: Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[0.220][SEVERE]: nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
#0 0x0000004d9d2e <unknown>
#1 0x0000004ab14b <unknown>
#2 0x0000006b42b8 <unknown>
#3 0x00000061eedb <unknown>
#4 0x000000530c67 <unknown>
#5 0x000000516e8b <unknown>
#6 0x000000508aa7 <unknown>
#7 0x000000478d2a <unknown>
#8 0x00000060bb39 <unknown>
#9 0x000000609b44 <unknown>
#10 0x0000004da266 <unknown>
#11 0x0000004acdc5 <unknown>
#12 0x0000004ad0b8 <unknown>
#13 0x0000004ad40b <unknown>
#14 0x0000004af079 <unknown>
#15 0x0000004b9b6e <unknown>
#16 0x0000004cd7e2 <unknown>
#17 0x0000004ca793 <unknown>
#18 0x7fa08ab376ba start_thread
#19 0x7fa08822882d clone

Feb 08, 2017 4:02:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
OS = linux, Browser = 
Test case = LoginTest
browserName = firefox
Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 62.272 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
runBrowser(testCases.ApplicationTableTempl)  Time elapsed: 61.716 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1),platform=Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'jenkins', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-62-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1),platform=Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: d438dd092af3c51f3f72ca37527e0e91
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:882)
at factory.BrowserFactory.getBrowser(BrowserFactory.java:57)
at testCases.ApplicationTableTempl.runBrowser(ApplicationTableTempl.java:34)

runBrowser(testCases.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 0.207 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
t java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
at utility.Utility.startRecording(Utility.java:183)
at testCases.LoginTest.runBrowser(LoginTest.java:34)


Results :

Failed tests: 
ApplicationTableTempl.runBrowser:34 » NoSuchSession no such session
(Driver ...
LoginTest.runBrowser:34 » AWT Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as...
```